# What is best design pattern for gatling testcases

Tags: scala, selenium, gatling, stress-testing

I am working on gatling stess test cases in scala since 1 month. 
I am kind of new to it.
I am writing normal/plain test cases in gatling.
Following what they have mentioned in https://gatling.io/docs/current/quickstart/ .
I am writing test cases as follows

```
package computerdatabase // 1

import io.gatling.core.Predef._ // 2
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

class BasicSimulation extends Simulation { // 3

  val httpConf = http // 4
    .baseURL("http://computer-database.gatling.io") // 5
    .acceptHeader("text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8") // 6
    .doNotTrackHeader("1")
    .acceptLanguageHeader("en-US,en;q=0.5")
    .acceptEncodingHeader("gzip, deflate")
    .userAgentHeader("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0")

  val scn = scenario("BasicSimulation") // 7
    .exec(http("request_1")  // 8
    .get("/")) // 9
    .pause(5) // 10

  setUp( // 11
    scn.inject(atOnceUsers(1)) // 12
  ).protocols(httpConf) // 13
}
```

But still I think there is better way to write gatling test cases using different design pattern like what we used to write in selenium (Page factory pattrern or keeping pages in different classes rather than writing all code in same test class). I am unaware of design patterns used in writing effective test cases for gatling. I have 2000 test cases. So which are design patterns I must consider, so that writing test case will be small effort and modularity will be maintained?

Comment: Mentioned here https://gatling.io/docs/current/advanced_tutorial/#advanced-tutorial ..last part of your link